# Getting errors while trying to inject code into Microsoft Teams

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to run inject some js into microsoft teams with node integration. I have managed to run my code just by adding "app" folder with "package.json" and "index.js" into "resources" folder of teams installation. But the problem is after loading some of my code and then trying to continue loading teams normally it errors out with "Looks like a few files are missing; re-install Microsoft Teams or try again.". I know this is possible because other electron apps like Discord start normally after injecting code.

PS. I'm sorry if this is confusing English is not my first language and this is kind of complicated to explain. Also "Better discord" project managed to use of this type of injection.

index.js

```
console.log("Custom code loaded. Loading teams...")
require("../app.asar")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried anything like this, but perhaps there's some kind of security, like signing of code, in Microsoft Teams that Discord doesn't do. Also to be aware, what you're doing here will only work on Desktop Teams, not web or mobile.

Comment: It's not a security problem I found out that this error occurs because teams can't find some html files. But those files only exist in packaged app.asar. I can't figure out how it reads them inside of the app.asar and why it can't do it when I start run from index.js

Comment: You can actually build a tab/bot  if you want to exchange something on teams. You can go through this [samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples) for more info.